# JSON Structure and Return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am new to web services and found an api.php file that I was able to hook up to my MSSQL server and retrieve information without problem, so that was great. I would now like to take the data that I am pulling and present it in an html page. I am not sure how to do this and have been doing a lot of reading to try and figure it out. I have run the data returned through a JSON validator and it validates.  Can anyone give me advice on how to make this display on a webpage (this is for proof of concept). I am on IIS... I have tried many things, the latest is:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
    </head>
        <body>
            <?php
            $json = file_get_contents('https://myurl.com/rest/api.php/content?filter=category,cs,10&columns=id_cr,title');
            $data = json_decode($json);
            echo "<pre>";
                print_r($data);
            echo "</pre>";
            exit;
        ?>
        </body>
</html>
```

Here is how the JSON data output looks - not sure how to access the data as variables within this format...

```
{
 "content_data": {
  "columns": [
   "id",
   "title"
  ],
  "records": [
   [
    41901,
    "Resources for Educational Excellence"
   ],
   [
    44230,
    "The Khan Academy"
   ],
   [
    145925,
    "Educating Your Child at Home"
   ],
  ]
 }
}
```

:::FIXED:::
I finally got my code to work!  So, the final code looks like this...

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <?php
                $json = file_get_contents('http://myurl.com/rest_api/api_test.php/content_data?filter=category,cs,10&columns=id,title');
                $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
                foreach ($data['content_data']['records'] as $rec) { 
                    echo $rec[0] .' '. $rec[1] . '<br />'; 
                } 
           ?>
     </body>
</html>
```

So the problem ended up being that when I had my api_data on my https server, I was not able to pull back any results into my php page, but when I moved the api_test.php file to the http server it worked like a charm.  Can anyone explain why that happened?  Thanks!

Also, I just wanted to thank everyone for the assistance, it was a hard project for me, but I learned a lot and next time should be easier :)

Comment: Are you trying to display it inside a table?

Comment: I was thinking that would work or just a list of titles... I would like it to be on a responsive page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you would be able to access the data easier if you set the second parameter of json_decode to TRUE to make it all arrays.

That means with your data:

```
$json = '{
 "content_data": {
  "columns": [
   "id",
   "title"
  ],
  "records": [
   [
    41901,
    "Resources for Educational Excellence"
   ],
   [
    44230,
    "The Khan Academy"
   ],
   [
    145925,
    "Educating Your Child at Home"
   ],
  ]
 }
}';
```

You would then be able to get the data like this:

```
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach( $data['content_data']['records'] as $record )
{
    echo '<p>' . $record[0] . '<br />
    ' . $record[1] . '</p>';
}
```

I just tested this code, and it works:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.myurl.com/rest_api/api_test.php/content_data?filter=assignments_list,cs,c010&columns=id_cr,title');

$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach( $data['content_data']['records'] as $record )
{
    echo '<p>' . $record[0] . '<br />
    ' . $record[1] . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added the code above, but when I go to the page, I don't get anything....just blank.   I have yet to be able to pull the JSON data back into a .php page - although when I put the URL in the browser I get back the data fine...  I feel like I am missing something, I just don't know what :)

Comment: I have seen (as recently as this week) people that were getting json from external resources where the json was corrupt, had extra whitespace, had urlencoded entities, etc. You say you can see the json in a browser, but that's not the same as seeing the raw json. If you allow access to the actual URL, I can help.

Comment: See my updated answer. At the bottom I actually test the code, and it works for me. If you copy just my code into a PHP fle and run it, you'll see that it does work.

Comment: Here are the results from the URL:

{"content_data":{"columns":["id_cr","title"],"records":[[41901,"Federal Resources for Educational Excellence"],[44230,"The Khan Academy"],[145925,"Educating Your Child at Home"],[147803,"Organisations and Resources for Primary Schools"]]}}

Comment: When I went to your URL (which is no longer available), I saw a lot more json than that. When I try to use your json string, I get an error. It's no good. So direct from the URL was fine, but your string is not. The json validator here https://jsonlint.com/ show what looks like whitespace in one of the numbers. It's the number 9 in 41901.

Comment: I agree with Brian on this one.

Comment: Thanks, I copied it into my php file...

    <!doctype html>
                <?php
                    $json = file_get_contents('urlhere');
                    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
                    foreach( $data['content_data']['records'] as $record ) {
                        echo '<p>' . $record[0] . '<br />
                        ' . $record[1] . '</p>';
                    }
             ?>
I am still just getting a blank page...   ::sigh::

Comment: Thanks Brian, I did copy only a portion of the json string and left in a comma that wasn't supposed to be there, the url validates though...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can parse the json data to html table with column names on top.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
    </head>
        <body>
        <?php
            $json = file_get_contents('https://myurl.com/rest/api.php/content?filter=category,cs,10&columns=id_cr,title');
            $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
        ?>
        <table>
            <!--column names-->
            <tr>
                <?php
                foreach ($data['content_data']['columns'] as $cols) {
                    ?>
                    <td><?= $cols ?></td>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tr>

            <!--record rows-->
            <tr>
                <?php
                foreach ($data['content_data']['records'] as $rec) {
                    ?>
                    <td><?= $rec[0] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $rec[1] ?></td>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Chad, I have adjusted the code in my PHP page, but I am still unable to get any data returned the $file_get_contents url - the url works fine if I put it in a browser, but does not pull anything in on the php page...

Comment: It would be great if you can give the actual URL so we can check if the returned JSON is valid and can be read by PHP. Thanks!

Comment: Here are the results from the URL: {"content_data":{"columns":["id_cr","title"],"records":[[41901,"Federal Resources for Educational Excellence"],[44230,"The Khan Academy"],[145925,"Educating Your Child at Home"],[147803,"Organisations and Resources for Primary Schools"]]}}

Answer (score 0):

As I tested the JSON String it wasn´t valid.

```
               [
                145925,
                "Educating Your Child at Home"
               ], //this comma has json_decode failing and outputs null
```

you might check your resource, where you get the JSONString.

For accessing the values of the JSONObject you can simply acces them in PHP like an array. Therefore just use TRUE as the second parameter on your $json_decode.

```
$json_decode($data, TRUE);
```

Then for example you could do this. You could write it much cleaner with less code, but i tested this and it works:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
</head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $json = '{
             "content_data": {
              "columns": [
               "id",
               "title"
              ],
              "records": [
               [
                41901,
                "Resources for Educational Excellence"
               ],
               [
                44230,
                "The Khan Academy"
               ],
               [
                145925,
                "Educating Your Child at Home"
               ]
              ]
             }
            }';

        $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
        var_dump($data);
        echo "<pre>";
            //print out the data a
        echo "<h2>Data</h2>";

        echo "<table>";

        echo "<tr>";
        //access column data and print out the values
        echo "<td>". $data['content_data']['columns'][0]."</td>";
        echo "<td>". $data['content_data']['columns'][1]."</td>";

        echo "</tr>";



        for($i = 0; $i < count($data['content_data']['records']);$i++ ) {

            echo "<tr id=" .$data['content_data']['records'][$i][0] . ">";

            //acces records and print a table with that data
            echo "<td>" . $data['content_data']['records'][$i][0]."</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $data['content_data']['records'][$i][1]."</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
        }


        echo "</table>";
            //var_dump($data->content_data);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit;
    ?>
    </body>
```

The result would be this

[Result of that code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B528.png)

Comment: Thanks for the code above.  I have been working on this all day and I am at a loss.   When I copied your code above, I get NULL for the data dump. I think it is because I am passing parameters with in my url in the $file_get_content.... I don't know...